# Canvas drawing lines creating 1 curved & 1 non-curved at same time

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make it so that it's just 1 curved line but for some reason it's creating it behind the jagged one I don't want.

I tried adding & removing and for some reason the line still draws when I deleted "beginPath()." But with the bezierCurveTo, it remains jagged but forms a smooth line again when I add "beginPath()" again.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

ctx.strokeStyle = 'hue(100%, 75%, 50%)';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;

let points = [];


function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  var px2 = points.map(point => point.x)[2];
  var py2 = points.map(point => point.y)[2];
  var px1 = points.map(point => point.x)[1];
  var py1 = points.map(point => point.y)[1];
  var px0 = points.map(point => point.x)[0];
  var py0 = points.map(point => point.y)[0];

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(px2, py2);

  if (points.length > 3) {
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(px1, py1, px0, py0, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  }

  var slope = ((lastY - e.offsetY) + 1) / (Math.abs(lastX - e.offsetX) + 1);

  if (slope < -0.5) {
    if (ctx.lineWidth < 15) {
      ctx.lineWidth++;
    }
  } else {
    if (ctx.lineWidth > 3) {
      ctx.lineWidth -= 1;
    }
  }

  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];

  points.unshift({
    x: lastX,
    y: lastY,
    size: ctx.lineWidth,
    color: ctx.strokeStyle,
    mode: "draw"
  });
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  points = [];
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false);
```

```html
<canvas id="draw"></canvas>
```

I'm expecting the end result to just have 1 curved line and remove the jagged one layered on top.

You'll also only be able to see the 2 layers when you draw a curve really fast.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you are after... One thing: you are caling stroke() before you define your path. This means you are always one frame late. You'll probably want to move this call at the end of your `draw` function. Otherwise... not sure what's the point in having th gCO to multiply here. But none of these seem to relate with what you describe (that I really have trouble to understand)

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for replying. Here is an example of what happens when I move the cursor quickly enough to see the multi layers. https://imgur.com/a/Xrbyxel I'm not sure why they decided to branch out that way instead of staying as 1 consistent line. It seems to still be doing it after the changes I made.

Comment: Ah I think I see better what you are after. Basically, [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbymkwq0/) which uses hardcoded values, you'd want the inner of the bumps to be filled right? Just like if it was a single stroke.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh uhm it's more like just having this https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/ . I think I went wrong somewhere while doing this. This is my older file without the bezierCurveTo https://serelath.github.io/hand-lettering-canvas/ and I wanted to smooth it out. I just found that after placing bezierCurveTo in, it created that branchlike structure when drawing.

Comment: Yes, that's quite logical, the bezierCurveTo will fatten curves by interlacing points. So in an arc, what would have been two straight lines will become two interlaced curves, that will get seen as a single fatter and rounder stroke. You can see it better by changing the strokeStyle at every stroke to reveal each of the three paths that actually get generated this way: https://jsfiddle.net/hkLb82po/ Not sure there is too much to be done though... Calculating the distance between points on these bezier curves will not be an easy task...

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you so much for the help! I'm guna play around it some more but it seems I made it so that the moveTo came onto the control points instead of the bezier curve that was the problem. Once I get that down I think that should be good.